# Pagination component structure

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-component

We develop a pagination component for our components library two days before.

And when component been done we have some discussion on component properties structure.

---

**Variant 1**

```
<pagination :total-pages="(totalPages as number)"
            v-model="(currentPage as number)" />
```

---

**Variant 2**

```
<pagination :total="(totalItems as number)"
            :per-page="(perPage as number)"
            v-model="(currentPage as number)">
```

---

What do you think about these structures? Which is better for the public components library?

Comment: where did you send the data itself to pagination component (data = data you want to make pagination on)?.

Comment: @elichenI its question not about code. Only about props. Which one is better? With total_pages or total_items

Comment: Normally paging component will have a access to the data itself. So not really need for total items at all. But maybe you still want it for some cases. Anyway i think the second one is better. Its more clear what is going on and from my experience paging plugins normally has perPage property. In the first one you dont have a control how much per page(or i missing something)